# Why did these characters [spoiler] not die in the Dr Who "The Crimson Horror" episode?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode [The Crimson Horror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crimson_Horror)

The Doctor, Clara, and 3 others were all inside the

> Rocket chamber, and Mrs Gillyflower launched the rocket with the backup launch switch.

Why did they not

> Die a horrible death from the rocket blast?  Instead they just turned to face the corner and somehow didn't get incinerated?

It wasn't very realistic for this to happen this way, how was a big detail like this missed?

Comment: "Boy, I really hope somebody got fired for that blunder."

Answer (score 18):

Doctor Who laughs in the face of physics. And then punches physics, steals its wallet and leaves it bleeding in a ditch.

There is no reason for this given in the episode; if you really want to you can assume that the Doctor had some kind of forcefield to protect them. If you subscribe to the view that Mr. Sweet was intelligent and giving Mrs. Gillyflower technical advice, then perhaps the rocket runs on some kind of super-advanced dinosaur-technology which has a convenient side-effect of not roasting nearby people.

Comment: Upvoted just on the grounds of the 1st paragraph.  For *Doctor Who*, that's an entire answer in itself.  No more need be said.

Comment: "Super-advanced dinosaur-technology" made my day, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this wouldn't work in real life, but I bet what they were going for was Small rocket + Silo not being airtight = a burn that is directed more toward the ground then the sides of the silo. It would still at least have burned their flesh to a crispy level, but this is Doctor Who we are talking about. It is possible the rocket had a sort of field around it to keep it protected from tampering (hence why they didn't try to sabotage it instead of the highly dangerous substance they were trying to load it with), and that field kept the flame directed toward the ground. But in reality, yes they would have all been char-broiled before the rocket ever lifted off the ground.